# Libreoffice Scatter Plot - Gradient Fill Points

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm using LibreOffice Calc and I'm trying to create a scatter plot with some data that I have.

[This is what my graph looks like so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgaDj.png)

I want to color the individual points by a gradient of their value, how we would do in Python or R,
[This is what I want it to look like (minus the black background)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSuYY.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried and what research have you done regarding this?